# How do i make a self hosted wcf accept REST/JSON?

Tags: json, rest, wcf, rest-client

I have read here on SO in several posts that it is possible to create a selfhosted wcf REST service that accepts JSON as input. But i cant get it to work, im banging my head against the same rock over and over it seems :(

This is my very basic code that i cant get working.
Im using .net 4.6.1 in VS 2017

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
//[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Save")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
bool Save(BatchOfRows request);
}

public bool Save(BatchOfRows request)
{
    return true;
}
```

---

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/");

// Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
var selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
try
{
// Step 3: Add a service endpoint.
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

// Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

// Step 5: Start the service.
selfHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

// Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
selfHost.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException ce)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
    selfHost.Abort();
}
```

I then connect with this code

```
        string url = @"http://127.0.0.1:8000";

        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest("Save", Method.POST);

        var b = new BatchOfRows();
        b.CaseTableRows.Add(new AMCaseTableRow { PROJID = "proj1", CASEID = "case1" });
        b.CaseTableRows.Add(new AMCaseTableRow { PROJID = "proj2", CASEID = "case2", DEVICEID = "device2" });

        var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BatchOfRows));

        ser.WriteObject(stream1, b);

        stream1.Flush();
        stream1.Position = 0;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream1);
        string payload = reader.ReadToEnd();

        request.AddParameter("Save",payload);

        var response = client.Post(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

In the respose i get this back.

```
"StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"
  Content: ""
  ContentEncoding: ""
  ContentLength: 0
  ContentType: ""
  Cookies: Count = 0
  ErrorException: null
  ErrorMessage: null
  Headers: Count = 3
  IsSuccessful: false
  ProtocolVersion: {1.1}
  RawBytes: {byte[0]}
  Request: {RestSharp.RestRequest}
  ResponseStatus: Completed
  ResponseUri: {http://127.0.0.1:8000/Save}
  Server: "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
  StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType
  StatusDescription: "Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'."
```

I cant get it to work! I have tried with different client implementations with the same result.
In every answer i check it sais to just use

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

And i should be good. But its not working and im getting abit frustrated as this is the simplest example i can think of.

So what am i doing wrong?

I have used the same type of implementation before, but for a SOAP project, and that is working just fine. I cant do that this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, we need to use WebHttpBinding to create Restful style WCF service. 
Here is an example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
Webservicehost is also need to host the service when we create the Restful style service. Alternatively, we could add WebHttpBehavior endpoint behavior to the host, like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9999");
    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
    using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),uri))
    {
        ServiceEndpoint se=sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService),binding,"");
        se.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());


        sh.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is ready....");

        Console.ReadLine();
        sh.Close();
    }
}
```

Result.
[image]
Besides, For the **BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped** attribute, Please pay attention to the data format when we have the Custom object parameter.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
bool Save(BatchOfRows request);
```

Assumed that the BatchOfRows has one ID property. Based on your definition, the Json Data should be.

> { “request”:{“ID”:1}}

For details.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: But now i have another problem...i simplified my BatchOrRows class alot to make sure it wasn't that that was the issue. And now i have added the full class again, and it stops forking. If i remove all datetime properties it works...any idea how to slove that?

Comment: never mind...got it working with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468881/619791

Comment: It worked very well for http...but not for https. Is there much needed to change to get https working also?

Comment: Lest that a verbose discussion in the comment, please post a new thread, I will follow up.

Comment: I posted it as a new question, i really really hope you can help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678485/example-of-a-post-request-to-wcf-selfhosted-rest-service-over-https