# Example of a POST request to WCF selfhosted REST service over HTTPS

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, post, https

There are numerus question about the same topic here on SO, but none of them seems to give a complete answer. I have checked most of the questions/answers and tested, tested and tested. So hopefully this question will help me and others struggling.

**The question.**

How do i set up WCF selfhosted REST service that works over https?
This is how I have tried setting up the service and clients. It doesn't work! But i feel that im very close with every change, but im not reaching the goal.

So, can someone help me with a complete example that is working with a REST endpoint, selfhosted WCF over HTTPS and a POST request? I have tried puzzling together bits and pieces from everywhere and i cant get it working!
Should i give up? Choose another technology?

So, some code:

[ServiceHost]

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:443");

        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

        using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), uri))
        {
            ServiceEndpoint se = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "");
            //se.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

            // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            // If not, add one
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = false; //**http**
            smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true; //**https**
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            // Add MEX endpoint
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(), //**https**
              "mex"
            );

            var behaviour = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
            behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

            Console.WriteLine("service is ready....");
            sh.Open();

            Console.ReadLine();
            sh.Close();
        }
```

[IService]

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "Datarows_IN/")]
    [OperationContract]
    bool Save(BatchOfRows batchOfRows);
}
```

[Service]

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public bool Save(BatchOfRows batchOfRows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Save");
        return true;
    }
}
```

[BatchOfRows] - simplified

```
[DataContract]
public class BatchOfRows
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; } = -1;
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; } = "Hej";
}
```

This is build upon SO answer after SO answer and Microsoft tutorials.
I dont even know where what example started and the others ended.
I began from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554374/619791
And that worked very well until i tried enabling https, then everything stopped working.

Here are some client code that i have tried.

[WebClient]

```
            string uri = "https://localhost:443/Datarows_IN";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var b = new BatchOfRows();
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };

            string str2 = "{\"batchOfRows\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b, settings) + "}";
            string result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", str2);
```

[HttpClient]

```
            string str2 = "{\"batchOfRows\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b, settings) + "}";
            var contentData = new StringContent(str2, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            //string result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", str2);
            //HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:443/Datarows_IN", b).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:443/Datarows_IN", contentData).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

[ChannelFactory]

```
            //var c = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:443/Datarows_IN"));
            var c = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:443/"));
            ((WebHttpBinding)c.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            ((WebHttpBinding)c.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            c.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            var aw = c.CreateChannel();

            var b = new ModuleIntegration.Client.Objects.BatchOfRows();
            aw.Save(b);
```

None of the clients work. If i debug my Service endpoint is never triggered.
This is the current error that im getting:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
    <Code>
        <Value>Sender</Value>
        <Subcode>
            <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</Value>
        </Subcode>
    </Code>
    <Reason>
        <Text xml:lang="sv-SE">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</Text>
    </Reason>
</Fault>
```

Please help! Why is this so hard?!?

Comment: If you're only using the REST endpoints, just make use .net WebApi instead. Only use WCF if you have to use SOAP. WCF is quite verbose, and a lot of work to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is missing the [`WebHttpBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior?view=netframework-4.8).

Without it, the `WebInvoke` attribute does nothing, and the path `"Datarows_IN"` is not recognized as an action.

Here's the full (works for me) service host code:

```
var binding = new WebHttpBinding()
{
    Security = {
        Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport
    }
};
var baseUri = new Uri("https://localhost:443");

using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseUri))
{
    var metadata = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (metadata == null) {
        metadata = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadata);
    }
    metadata.HttpsGetEnabled = true;

    var endpoint = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "/");
    endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready....");
    sh.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Service started. Press <ENTER> to close.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    sh.Close();
}
```

Comment: And with that small change everything works!!! You are my hero!
I had the webHttpBehavior in my code before, but i had to comment it out, can remember why now, but i crashed the code when i switched to https from http.
I want to upvote more!! =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets seem very cautious, which caused the above error, and namely, we should add the WebHttpBehavior.
However, there is one more thing we should pay attention to.
Ordinarily, the service is required to provide a certificate to encrypt and sign the communication between the server-side and the client-side when we hosting the service over HTTPS in IIS.
Thereby, we should bind a certificate theoretically when we use self-host, or the service should not be work properly.
Why does this service endpoint address work well? The only explanation is that we have bound a certificate to the port somewhere, such as IIS, there is a website with an https binding and use the default port.
If the custom port does not associate with a certificate we should bind a certificate by using the below command.

> Netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:portnumber
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert
By default, the certificate could merely be set up when it is stored in the Local Machine instead of the Current User. We could manage the certificate with the below command.

> Certlm.msc

Wish you have good luck.
At last, WCF is not aimed at designing the Restful style service. We should consider Asp.net WebAPI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: You are correct. I have bound a certificate to the with the netsh command. I just forgot to mention that.
For the next iteration of the code i will see if i can refactor it to WebAPI, but for now that is not in the timescope.